# How can I access The request.data Inside My post_save signal after creating the Model Objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

I want to create Projects with Documents

But It took time So i wanna add document after creating the projects

But I am giving Documents related details inside my request body

```
# Define the signal receiver function
@receiver(post_save, sender=Project)
def attach_documents_to_project(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        attachments_data = instance.request.data.get('document')
```

Comment: request.data is not working here, but the data you can find in instance.id or instance.document

Comment: @TanveerAhmad is there anyway to pass my req. Body data as argument and fetch it inside signal

Comment: Nope, there is no way, i just try it but it gives me error TypeError: execute_task_on_create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request

Comment: You *don't*. signals, just like models are request *unaware*.

Answer (score 2):

**You *don't***. signals, just like models are request *unaware*. This is a core design feature of most [*model-view-viewmodel (MVVM)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) architectures. In fact it is not even said that there *is* a request involved. You could also create or update or remove records with a [*management command* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-management-commands/).

These are all reasons [*not* to use signals <sup>[django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html)<sup>†</sup> in the first place. If something is request-oriented, it belongs in a view, not in the model layer, where signals essentially reside. You can define a helper function that you then invoke in view(s) where you want to trigger this logic.

---

<sup>†</sup> disclosure: I am the author if that article.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `_request` attribute for the `instance` before calling the save method and access that attribute inside the receiver method.

Inside views.py/serializers.py:

```
instance._request = request
instance.save()
```

Inside receiver method:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Project)
def attach_documents_to_project(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            attachments_data = instance._request.data.get('document')
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Make sure to wrap the statement between try/except or put it under `if hasattr(instance, "_request"):`.

Comment: Bweuh, no that is horrible, this severly violates the MVVM architecture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm

Comment: attach_documents_to_project(sender=Project, instance=current_project, created=True,
                                            request_data=request.data) is it ok to pass my signal like this after I have done serializer.save() inside my view.py file